# Downvotes being used as retaliation/something else?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this can be asked but since [this discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/downvoting-shouldnt-people-comment-why-they-downvoted) mentions that multiple downvotes with no explanation can be consulted on meta, I decided to just ask.

Anyway, I just noticed that I've been getting a downvote on most of my recent answers. I would more than understand if these downvotes were given to my older answers as I might not be as knowledgeable about certain topics before as I am now. However, these are the answers that have been downvoted:

- [How does S-Class heroes' power compare to threat levels?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51516/how-does-s-class-heroes-power-compare-to-threat-levels/51539#51539)
- [Who are the Heroes that Sweet Mask acknowledged?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51480/who-are-the-heroes-that-sweet-mask-acknowledged/51488#51488)
- [Why does Iida call Ochako Uraraka-Kun?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51437/why-does-iida-call-ochako-uraraka-kun/51438#51438)
- [When is Naruto using Kurama one tail](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/when-is-naruto-using-kurama-one-tail/51352#51352)

If there's anything common among these answers, it's that they were recently given and are not without sources so they are easily verified. There is little speculation, if not none, that is needed as these questions can be answered with facts either from the manga or from other sources which made me wonder what could be the reason for the downvotes. If you think they need improvement or there's anything else wrong with it, it would be greatly appreciated if someone can enlighten me. I am always open to suggestions since I know I can always learn from them.

I'm not really worried about downvotes, as it is a user's right. What I'm worried about is that it is being used for something else. I am not 100% sure but I'm 99% sure this is just one user and I think I know who this user that's been giving me downvotes recently. My suspicion as to why is that I've been recently stating in my answers that it has verifiable sources as I've noticed recent answers with no sources on new questions in the main site.

It would be greatly appreciated if that user would just confront me directly and tell me what his/her problem with me is (whether on chat or here) instead of resorting to downvotes just because he/she don't like being given a suggestion on answers or that a sourced answer was preferred over his/her. If I'm wrong and I'm just paranoid, then I sincerely apologize to whoever he/she is that I suspected.

What do you guys think? Am I just being paranoid and should leave this be? I'm just worried other users would be deterred from staying on this site because of downvotes being used as some sort of retaliation or something else.

Update 1: As of typing this update, two more downvotes, likely from the same user, on the following answers happened: [Which volume has Mikasa's backstory?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51380/which-volume-has-mikasas-backstory/51382#51382) [Is King's luck natural or does he have some sort of "luck superpower"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/51474/is-kings-luck-natural-or-does-he-have-some-sort-of-luck-superpower/51477#51477)

Update 2: Points were returned. Thanks to the admins/moderators! User still has not made any attempt to contact or give any reason for what happpened. Hoping this will be the last time this would happen to anyone else.

Note: I am not trying to provoke anyone here, just wanted to have some peace of mind.

Comment: There has been a wave of questionable serial voting recently; [Suspicious downvotes on recently asked questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4193)

Comment: I found your answers hard to read. And so would have just ignored them. Maybe some people think that it's worthy of downvotes instead. I've suggested a couple of edits to improve this.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thanks for the suggestion! I've seen your suggested edits ad no offense but I'm not sure since you just changed the formatting and some grammatical mistakes were made in the suggestion. I've made sure they are of correct grammar and I've arranged my thoughts in order not to confuse others. By 'hard to read' what do you mean exactly? Can you clarify? I find it a bit vague.

Comment: @W.Are I mostly changed the format/arrangement. I'm interested in what grammatical errors I introduced. I like OPM, but reading your answers were a chore to me - so it was hard to read.

Comment: Still cannot understand why you think 'reading your answers were a chore - so it was hard to read' :) Did I incur grammatical mistakes? Was there a lack/too much information? Did I miss some information? Was the flow of my discussion hard to follow? If you want, I can explain to you why my flow of discussion was like that and why the edit deviates to what I want to impart with my answer...

Comment: You have a lot of unneeded information, "Here's a sourced answer for you" is just noise. A lot of the second link is noise like this. This noise can be removed by using correct formatting. I found the first hard to read because it doesn't answer the question until halfway through. And the added information (that I moved to the bottom) is IMO useless trivia. The second answer is poorly formatted with a lot of noise that makes it hard to see if they only acknowledge S-class heroes. I changed it so that you can see the heroes, ranks and sources in a couple of seconds. Rather than minutes.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The purpose of my statement about a sourced answer is, for me, not noise. As I've said in my post above, I recently noticed questions without any sources at all. It was meant as a way for the OP to easily identify it as a sourced answer so that even among the multiple unsourced answer given, he/she can determine which is which since this site requires sources. I know it may not be needed at all times but seeing the recent wave of unsourced answers, I felt it was necessary. <continued below>

Comment: For the first answer, I usually do this on my answers. Discuss a bit about the topic before giving your answers. This is for the benefit of the asker to which the answer is directed to in case that particular information is not clear. If you think this is useless, you can just skip over it while reading. Seeing as it was marked as answered by the OP and there were no clarifications asked, it seems to me that he/she understood the answer just fine. <continued below>

Comment: For the second answer, I think it is an overstatement to say that it would take you minutes to read. It has less than ten, short sentences, each hero acknowledged separated by a paragraph while the last paragraph acts as the conclusion. Again, regarding the statement that it is sourced, I felt it was necessary as a previous answer gave a lot of unsourced information. This is to help the OP identify which answer has sources and which has not, given the recent answers from different questions without sources.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Although I do admit that now that you mentioned it, the statement 'here's a sourced answer...' does seem like noise or even unnecessary. I'll try to avoid them in the future, thanks! :)

Comment: "you can just skip over it while reading" is hard to do when your answer has no formatting, guiding me where I can skip to without skipping too much. I've never said that your answers are not understandable or lack information, I've only said that they have unneeded noise and are poorly formatted. I don't think it's an overstatement as it did take me a couple of minutes to read.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Alright. I meant no offense whatsoever in my earlier comments. I'll take this into mind in the future when giving other answers. Thanks! :) I appreciate it. I just hope that the user who downvoted my answers explain what he/she saw wrong like you did so that I can better understand, instead of resorting to unreasonable downvotes.

Comment: Woah! I've only just got the move this discussion to chat message :O No offense taken, feel free to decline my suggested edits if you don't think they're good. :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Nah, I'll accept them since you raised a good point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the best way to have someone look into this is to either flag one of the downvoted posts so the moderation team can investigate the issue, or use [the contact form](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to have someone from the Support Team look at it.

I'll also add that a lot of times the system automatically invalidates these votes, especially if they're cast over a short period of time.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind next time. Thanks!